# What is the Russian code of procedure if a NATO missile strikes Russia by an accident?

Tags: russian-federation, nato

- [India fires missile into Pakistan after ‘technical malfunction’](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2022/mar/11/india-fires-missile-into-pakistan-after-technical-malfunction)

The above news says that India accidentally fired a supersonic missile into Pakistan. The most probable reason would be a technical malfunction. Luckily, the missile was not carrying any warhead i.e was unarmed, and the Indian Foreign Office (FO) also apologized for the error.

What happens if NATO accidentally fires a missile, without a warhead, into Russia in peacetime and then apologizes?

What is the Russian code of procedure in such cases?

Comment: Nobody knows, but maybe the same as with India and Pakistan. Here, Russia may be evil but not stupid. Typically, they wouldn't want to go to war just because of an accident.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depends on the specifics of the case. Anything from possible nuclear war (see the [Norwegian rocket incident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norwegian_rocket_incident), only worse) to Russia celebrating an intelligence windfall (see the [Iranian drone incident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019_Iranian_shoot-down_of_American_drone)).